using nginx host multiple django apps/docker in one server. return to root path not the apps' path
I have a django app. The code snippet for the function load_form(request) in views.py.
def load_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        newQAForm = QAForm(request.POST)
        if newQAForm.is_valid():
            instance = newQAForm.save(commit=False)
            instance.save(using='RadDataWarehouse')
            return redirect('confirmation')


and another function
def confirmation(request):
    return render(request, 'confirmation.html')


It runs well in local. It will direct it to http://127.0.0.1:8000/confirmation/ after save the form to database.
After I deployed it to linux server. I had a issue after save it to database. It will direct to https://abcdomain.com/confirmation/. But I suppose it will go to https://abcdomain.com/protocolqa/confirmation/.
The nginx.conf for the Reverse Proxy is below:

    location /protocolqa/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8511/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Script-Name /protocolqa;
            proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
        }


How to fix it and let it got to https://abcdomain.com/protocolqa/confirmation/

You need rewrite you url path using nginx rewrite.  Check for more information:
https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html

After I changed it to this, it works.
   def confirmation(request):            
        return render(request, 'confirmation.html')

